# Python 3.4 - str() nor int() conversion possible for list elements

Tags: python, string, list, int

I have following code:

```
list = ["1", 0]
list2 = ["2", "0"]

str(list[1])
int(list2[1])

print(type(list[1]))
print(type(list2[1]))

input()
```

My problem is, `list[1]` stays an integer just as `list2[1]` stays a string. Where is the logic behind this, and are there any other ways for a successful conversion?

Comment: Don't name the variable `list`. Change it to `list1`.

Comment: In my actual code, it is named something like epab, but I needed an intellegible example.

Comment: Nope! Don't use that even in examples

Comment: @MsXler, you won't win with Mr Pedantic a.k.a Bhargav Rao!

Answer (score 5):

`int` and `str` construct a *new* int or str based on the input.  They don't mutate the list in place -- in fact, they have no idea that the input value is contained in a list.

To change an element in the list, you need to *assign* the return value back into the list:

e.g.

```
lst[1] = str(lst[1])
```

Comment: Ah! Now that's a way simpler reason than I expected. Thanks for the quick solution!

Answer (score 1):

You just *call* the function, not assign it's resulting to something.

It should be this:

```
list[1] = str(list[1])
list2[1] = int(list2[1])
```

Then it will have the desired type.